# QGIS Line width transition

Tags: qgis

I have a shapelayer with lines (streets), each line has a value for the traffic on it. The value is shown by the width of each line. Now I want to smooth the transition between one segment that has e.g. the value 500 which goes into a segment with value 100. Any ideas?
I want to achieve more or less the same result, as in this post, only automatically for a larger dataset …
[Blend differing line thicknesses in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/252680/blend-differing-line-thicknesses-in-qgis)

Maybe a little graphic helps: Above what I got. Bottom, what I want to have. Each line segment has only 1 value, and I want to smooth the segments into each other.
[image]

Comment: Is there a reason the linked post wouldn't work for your situation?

Comment: Yes, as stated I need this to work automatically for a large dataset. If it was only for single lines, I would do it in Illustrator, but I need it for a whole Street Network …

Comment: If the arrow size is determined by the same value as the width, this can be applied to the entire network via layer styling options.

Comment: Why not do this with rule based styles mimicking what the other post shows?

Comment: It sounds to me, as you somehow know the solution – I just really dont know the HOW. How can I "tell" one line, to "look out" for the next line (which doesn’t have an attribute, saying it is the next line) and scale in width accordingly?

Comment: Maybe a little graphic helps: Above what I got. Bottom, what I want to have. Each line segment has only 1 value, and I want to smooth the segments into each other
https://www.dropbox.com/s/7lz557o3kp16jex/Bildschirmfoto%202018-03-05%20um%2014.43.32.png?dl=0

Answer (score 1):

This is not a complete solution, but it may provide a starting point that you can improve on.

Use an arrow symbol type. Add two numerical fields to your street layer: startwidth and endwidth. Use these fields to control the arrow width and arrow starting width.
[image]

The startwidth of each line feature should be the same as the endwidth of the line it connects to.

[image]

[image]

In my test example, I filled in the values for startwidth and endwidth manually. The next question would be how to automate these values.

Comment: Yes, great, thank you! Definitely a starting point! … any ideas about automatization anyone?

Comment: I think if you use a data type other than shapefile, there are ones where you can define have lines "know" that they're connected to each other. Concepts to look into would be topology and networks.